# Using @font-face rule to load fonts in JavaFX stylesheet doesn't work properly on Linux

Tags: java, linux, javafx, font-face

I have started coding my application on Windows and it is running perfectly fine, so I tried to test it on Linux, but then this is where the issue begun occuring.

I am getting an error (not actually an error but I prefer to call it as such) which says:

```
Nov 02, 2017 3:28:14 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
INFO: Could not load @font-face font [jar:file:/home/kuroro/Documents/java/PackageSigner2/build/output/packagesigner2.jar!/res/fonts/material/icons/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf]
```

I'm using `@font-face` rule to load the Material Design Icons font and the path is correctly assigned, means that the error pertains only to the `@font-face` rule and the `src` CSS property.

Here's my stylesheet declaring `@font-face` rule:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  src: url("/res/fonts/material/icons/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf");
}
```

I tried to build the application on both OS and run them (vice versa), but I still get the same error on Linux.

Here are some screenshot of my application running on Windows and Linux:

#### Windows 10 (64 bit)

[image: windows]

#### Xubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (32 bit)

[image: linux]

My JDK versions:

**WINDOWS**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

**LINUX**

```
kuroro@XUBUNTU:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Any possible idea how to overcome this issue?

---

**UPDATE**

I remember installing Material Design Icons font on my Windows 10 system before while developing a web document as @sillyfly said on the comments that it may be the reason why it is loading the fonts correctly on Windows. So I installed a fresh Windows 7 (32 bit) virtual machine with the latest JDK 8 to test it and it is working well.

Screenshot of my project built on Windows 7 (resource files are in their proper locations):

[image: windows7]

Still fail to load the fonts on Linux system.

Comment: Is the font itself installed on the Windows system? It may be that it can't find it there too, but takes a system-installed version. If this is the case, possibly the file isn't included in the JAR, or is not in the location you specified.

Comment: @sillyfly thanks for reminding me about system installed fonts. But they're not installed either on my Windows system, I've also checked the package and all resource files are in their proper locations.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is some issue with uppercase/lowercase, which Windows may ignore...

Comment: Hmm... maybe you are seeing this bug: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8173468  Seems like it should be solved in 8u152

Comment: @sillyfly I got it working on a Linux 64 bit system with the current latest JDK 9.0.1, and I also think that it may be the JDK version I'm using. Just an addition, I've also test the program with OpenJDK 8 and OpenJFX before posting this question, I switched to the Oracle 8 Installer package (apt-get) but both JDKs gives me this error. Thank you so much for helping me out with this problem, I highly appreciate it. Please post this as an answer so I can mark it then. This is the least that I can do in return.

Comment: @sillyfly I'll just notify users to use the update 152 instead of 151 because of this issue. It is now running perfectly with the 8u152 (official `tar` package). Thank you so much once again. Answer my question and I'll accept it as the answer. **CASE CLOSED**